# Navigation Drawer Back Pressed Fragment Doesn't Load

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I have a `navigation drawer with fragments`. At start, I display `Home fragment` as default.

There are options on navigation menu. In 2 fragments I have `SwipeRefreshLayout`. Until all `recyclerview` data are fetched then I display data and invisible `SwipeRefreshLayout`.

One of these fragments (included `SwipeRefReshLayout`) works fine but, in Home fragment something is wrong.

**For example(use case)**

You started app and you saw Home fragment

You clicked Profile fragment on navigation menu

You run onBackPressed(back button).

In this case data never loads and SwipeRefReshLayout is always spinning. (I also tried without refreshlayout, still same)

Any idea how to fix this? My thought is, its about displaying default fragment.

**Navigation Drawer Activity**

```
public class Page_Navigation extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    Fragment fragment;
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    NavigationView navigationView;

    SharedPreferences mSharedPref;
    DrawerLayout drawer;
    private Tracker mTracker;
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_page__navigation);

        //
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        TextView toolbar_head = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_head);
        ImageView toolbar_image = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_image);
        ImageView toolbar_profile = findViewById(R.id.toolbar_profile);
        drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        //

        AnalyticsApplication application = (AnalyticsApplication) getApplication();
        mTracker = application.getDefaultTracker();
        mTracker.setScreenName("page_navigation");
        mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());


        //FIRST SETTINGS
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        Typeface customFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "Montserrat-Medium.ttf");
        toolbar_head.setTypeface(customFont);

        //Get Sessions
        mSharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
        String session_user_name = mSharedPref.getString("session_user_name", "");
        String session_user_photo = mSharedPref.getString("session_user_photo", "");

        //Navigation Drawer
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        navigationView.setItemIconTintList(null);
        //

        View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        TextView nav_userName = (TextView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.textView_nav_userName);
        CircleImageView imageView_navigation = (CircleImageView) headerView.findViewById(R.id.imageView_navigation);
        Glide.with(getApplicationContext()).load(session_user_photo).into(imageView_navigation);
        nav_userName.setText(session_user_name);

        headerView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.START)) {
                    drawer.closeDrawer(Gravity.START);
                }

                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        showProfileFragment();
                    }
                }, 300);
            }
        });


        toolbar_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            }
        });

        toolbar_profile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Fragment fragment;
                FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragment = new Nav_Profile();
                fragmentTransaction = manager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.navContent, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }
        });

        displayDefaultFragment();

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.page__navigation, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.

        final int id = item.getItemId();


        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                switch (id) {
                    case R.id.nav_home:
                        fragment = new Nav_Home();
                        break;

                    case R.id.nav_contact:
                        fragment = new Nav_Contact();
                        break;

                    case R.id.nav_articles:
                        fragment = new Nav_Article();
                        break;

                    case R.id.nav_about:
                        fragment = new Nav_AboutUs();
                        break;

                    case R.id.nav_suggest:
                        fragment = new Nav_Suggest();
                        break;

                    case R.id.nav_share:
                        fragment = new Nav_Share();
                        break;

                    case R.id.nav_rateApp:
                        fragment = new Nav_RateApp();
                        break;


                }

                fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.navContent, fragment)
                        .addToBackStack(null)
                        .commit();

            }
        }, 350);


        return true;
    }

    public void displayDefaultFragment() {
        fragment = new Nav_Home();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.navContent, fragment).commit();

    }


    public void showProfileFragment() {
        fragment = new Nav_Profile();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.navContent, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
    }
}
```

**Home Fragment**

```
public class Nav_Home extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener{

    SharedPreferences mSharedPref;

    private SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefresh_home;

    private CardView item_homeTop_coupons, item_homeTop_draws, item_homeTop_event;
    private LinearLayout layout_all_article, layout_all_999;
    private ScrollView shimmer_home;

    private List<Model_ListItem> listNewItems;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView_item_home;

    private List<Model_Article> articleList;
    private RecyclerView recyclerView_article_home;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        fetchItemsNew();
        fetchArticlesNew();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_nav__home, container, false);
        item_homeTop_coupons = view.findViewById(R.id.item_homeTop_coupons);
        item_homeTop_draws = view.findViewById(R.id.item_homeTop_draws);
        item_homeTop_event = view.findViewById(R.id.item_homeTop_event);
        recyclerView_item_home = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_item_home);
        recyclerView_article_home = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView_article_home);
        layout_all_article = view.findViewById(R.id.layout_all_article);
        layout_all_999 = view.findViewById(R.id.layout_all_999);
        swipeRefresh_home = view.findViewById(R.id.swipeRefresh_home);
        shimmer_home = view.findViewById(R.id.shimmer_home);
        item_homeTop_coupons.setOnClickListener(this);
        item_homeTop_draws.setOnClickListener(this);
        item_homeTop_event.setOnClickListener(this);
        layout_all_999.setOnClickListener(this);
        layout_all_article.setOnClickListener(this);

        //first settngs
        mSharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(view.getContext());
        String session_user_email = mSharedPref.getString("session_user_email","");


        swipeRefresh_home.setRefreshing(true);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()){

            case R.id.item_homeTop_coupons:
                startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), Page_Coupon.class));
                break;

            case R.id.item_homeTop_draws:
                startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), Page_Draw.class));
                break;

            case R.id.item_homeTop_event:
                startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), Page_Event.class));
                break;

            case R.id.layout_all_999:
                //999 city search activity
                startActivity(new Intent(getContext(), Page_SearchCity.class));
                break;

            case R.id.layout_all_article:
                //article fragment
                Fragment fragment;
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                fragment = new Nav_Article();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.navContent, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                break;

        }
    }



    public void fetchItemsNew(){
        listNewItems = new ArrayList<>();
        API_Service api_service = Client.getRetrofitInstance().create(API_Service.class);
        Call<List<Model_ListItem>> call = api_service.fetchItemsNew();
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Model_ListItem>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Model_ListItem>> call, Response<List<Model_ListItem>> response) {

                if(response.code() == 200){

                    listNewItems = response.body();
                    Adapter_HomeItem adapter_homeItem = new Adapter_HomeItem(getContext(), listNewItems);
                    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
                            = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
                    recyclerView_item_home.setHasFixedSize(true);
                    recyclerView_item_home.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                    recyclerView_item_home.setAdapter(adapter_homeItem);

                    SnapHelper helper = new LinearSnapHelper();
                    helper.attachToRecyclerView(recyclerView_item_home);

                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Model_ListItem>> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });

    }

    public void fetchArticlesNew(){
        articleList = new ArrayList<>();
        API_Service api_service = Client.getRetrofitInstance().create(API_Service.class);
        Call<List<Model_Article>> callArticle = api_service.fetchArticlesNew();
        callArticle.enqueue(new Callback<List<Model_Article>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<Model_Article>> call, Response<List<Model_Article>> response) {

                if(response.code() == 200){

                    articleList = response.body();
                    Adapter_HomeArticles adapter_homeArticles = new Adapter_HomeArticles(getContext(), articleList);
                    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager
                            = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);
                    recyclerView_article_home.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                    recyclerView_article_home.setHasFixedSize(true);
                    recyclerView_article_home.setAdapter(adapter_homeArticles);


                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<Model_Article>> call, Throwable t) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: I moved fetching functions from `onCreate` to `onCreateView` and solved

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you must disable `SwipeRefreshLayout` spinning when successfully or not fetched data:

```
swipeRefresh_home.setRefreshing(false);
```

If you do not do this spinner will be spinning all the time.

Another problem is that you have one fragment and you try to assign to it Nav_Home fragment and Nav_Profile fragment.

```
Fragment fragment;

public void displayDefaultFragment() {
    fragment = new Nav_Home();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.navContent, fragment).commit();
}

public void showProfileFragment() {
    fragment = new Nav_Profile();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.navContent, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
}
```

Try to separate them and show like this:

```
Fragment homeFragment;
Fragment profileFragment;

public void displayDefaultFragment() {
    homeFragment = new Nav_Home();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.navContent, homeFragment).commit();
}

public void showProfileFragment() {
    profileFragment = new Nav_Profile();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.navContent, profileFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I've done all you said, but unfortunately it didn't solve my problem. Wherever I go back to "Home Fragment" its spinning and its not about fetching data. For example; if you click "home" from navigation menu, it comes within 2 seconds maximum. The only problem is when you click back button, it doesnt run that fragment class I think and doesnt run services. There should me something wrong in that fragment about stacking or something. (Edit: by the way running profile fragment is about action bar, there is a short cut to go profile fragment from action bar)

Comment: Found it, I called fetching functions in onCreated method, I moved them to onCreateView. I actually called them there for an error handling but anyway I need to do in this way.